# TruncatedSVD always reduces dataset to 1D

Tags: machine-learning, pca, scikit-learn, svd

I know that I have a large sparse matrix which I'm using `TruncatedSVD` to condense into a smaller number of dimensions. Here is my code:

```
def _apply_svd(X):
    def get_svd(**kwargs):
        return TruncatedSVD(algorithm='randomized',
                            random_state=42,
                            **kwargs)

    svd = get_svd()
    svd.fit(X)
    cumsum = np.cumsum(svd.explained_variance_ratio_)
    d = np.argmax(cumsum >= 0.95) + 1

    svd = get_svd(n_components=d)
    return svd.fit_transform(X)
```

I'm trying to find the least number of dimensions that will give me an explained variance ratio of 95%, then using that as the number of dimensions. For some reason, I'm always getting d=1 even if I increase the ratio to, say, 99%. Here's what a graph of the data looks like after running SVD with `n_components=2`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

My original comment was wrong. There is no error in that line of code.

I believe your issue comes from the default `n_components=2` parameter of TruncatedSVD. Because of this, `svd.variance_explained_ratio_` only has two components, presumably with explained variance of less than 0.95. So `cumsum >= 0.95` is always False, and `np.argmax` will return 0.

You'll just need to put a sufficiently large `n_components` argument into your `get_svd()` function.